# struct array element initialization

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, structure, element

how may i init below structure with these values:

```
struct test_str {
unsigned char Add[6];
unsigned int  d;
unsigned char c;
}my_str;
```

i tried this but resulted in error:

```
struct test_str {
unsigned char Add[6];
unsigned int  d;
unsigned char c;
}my_str {.Add[0]=0x11,.Add[0]=0x22,.Add[0]=0x33,
         .Add[0]=0x44,.Add[0]=0x55,.Add[0]=0x66,
         .d=0xffe,.c=10};
```

Answer (score 3):

In modern C++11 or later (as your question was originally tagged C++ only) you have what is called [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It works like this:

```
struct test_str {
    unsigned char Add[6];
    unsigned int  d;
    unsigned char c;
} my_str { {0x11,  0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66},
            0xffe, 
            10
         };

int main()
{}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87261348976986e6)

The inner pair of braces is not really necessary, but I prefer it for the sake of clarity.

PS: you should get your hands on a good introductory [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so you learn the basics of the language.

**EDIT**

In C (as you re-tagged your question) and pre C++11, you need an equal sign. Furthermore, in C the inner braces are not optional:

```
struct test_str {
    unsigned char Add[6];
    unsigned int  d;
    unsigned char c;
} my_str = { {0x11,  0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66},
             0xffe, 
             10
           };

int main()
{}
```

Comment: do u have any idea that CodevisionAVR supports aggregate initialization? ';' expected, but '{' found

Comment: @hosseinvalizadeh I have absolutely no idea. This is a standard feature though, and it should be accepted by any standard C++ compliant compiler. Does your question refer to C? If yes, please re-tag it.

Comment: tag edited ! i get this error: ';' expected, but '{' found

Comment: @hosseinvalizadeh See the updated edit, you need an `=` sign in C, and cannot miss the inner braces.

Comment: @hosseinvalizadeh You're welcome. If the answer addresses your issue, please accept it after a while (or other answer, if any), so other readers know that the issue has been solved.